# toggle button - click one and all toggles switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

--EDIT--

I have the toggle Button with which slides left and right. The toggle and animation are working fine, but the problem comes when adding more than one instance of toggle button on the same page. When I click on a toggle button, All the toggle buttons are using the same VAR. So if you open one and then click another one, the second one doesn't slide open because it thinks is suppose to close. Where would you put the isChecked var so that it is different for each instance?

js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/amQCN/11/

```
$(document).ready(function() {


var isChecked = false;
$('.toggle-radio-switch').click(function() {
    if (isChecked == true) {
        $(this).find('.radio-switch-slider').animate({'margin-left': '0px'},'150');
        isChecked = false;
        console.log("isChecked = " + isChecked);
    } else {
        $(this).find('.radio-switch-slider').animate({'margin-left': '34px'},'150');
        isChecked = true;
        console.log("isChecked = " + isChecked);
    };
});


});
```

radio-switch-slider is positioned on top of the contents and slides back and forth revealing yes or no

```
<div class="toggle-radio-switch" id="toggle3">
    <span>yes</span>
    <span>no</span>
    <div class="radio-switch-slider"></div>
</div>
```

**Working version incase anyone is wondering:**

Ended up just using this instead

```
$('.toggle-radio-switch').click(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.radio-switch-slider').css('margin-left')=="0px"){
        $(this).find('.radio-switch-slider').animate({'margin-left': '34px'},'150');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.radio-switch-slider').animate({'margin-left': '0px'},'150');
    }
});
```

Comment: I added a FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/amQCN/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting your `.toggle-radio-switch` elements are siblings.  Remove `.parent()` from your code.  It isn't needed since `.radio-switch-slider` is contained directly in `.toggle-radio-switch`

```
$(this).find('.radio-switch-slider')...
```

Comment: That's all it was... So obvious after you pointed that out, but now that each one is working individually, the var is not set locally so all the toggles are using the same var =/ How would you make the var local to each toggle in this script?

Comment: You could store it on the element itself using `data`  http://api.jquery.com/data/  or simply check the current value of `margin` to see which state it is in.

Comment: Thanks james, that worked... just stripped out the var and checked marin instead.